# Como executar uma função quando o mouse estiver sobre determinado elemento?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Como criar uma função genérica javascript que se execute apenas no elemento em que o mouse está em cima no momento?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essa funcionalidade que pretende obtem-se com um oscultador de eventos.

Tendo um seletor para selecionar o elemento pode juntar-lhe um oscultador. Ou seja:

```
var elemento = document.querySelector('div'); // escolher o elemento
elemento.addEventListener('mouseover', minhaFuncao); // adicionar o oscultador
```

Aí essa `minhaFuncao` terá como argumento o evento.

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/cyaj6g26/

Se quiser ter mais que um elemento com essa funcionalidade vai ter que fazer um ciclo for e aplicar esse oscultador a cada um deles.

Por exemplo:

```
var elementos = document.querySelectorAll('div');
for (var i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++) {
    elementos[i].addEventListener('mouseover', minhaFuncao);
}
```

#### Exemplo online: http://jsfiddle.net/cyaj6g26/1/

Se usar uma biblioteca como o MooTools ou o jQuery isso fica mais simples. Aí pode fazer respectivamente:

```
$$('div').addEvent('mouseover', minhaFuncao); // MooTools
$('div').on('mouseover', minhaFuncao); // jQuery
```

A vantagem é que fica mais fácil de escrever, a desvantagem é que fica um pouco mais lento e pesado para o computador/móvel que fôr correr o código.

---

Vale a pena referir que em alguns casos pode ser melhor usar somente CSS e não JavaScript. Por exemplo para fazer a côr de fundo mudar não é preciso JavaScript, CSS bastaria:

```
div:hover{
    color: #ccf;
}
```

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/cyaj6g26/2/

Comment: Acho que em português se diz *listener* mesmo :P

Comment: @brasofilo: "up"-ado :)

Comment: Caso real, lá no Braza *playground* tava tão batido que as constructoras resolveram chamar de *fun floor*. Caso fictício, *"-Mas como é que se diz isso em português? -Ah, acho que é plaigroundi mesmo"*.